# Consequences of uniform converegence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g_n(x)=n^2xe^{-nx}$ and given that $\int_0^2g_n(x)dx=1-a_n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then prove that $g_n$ converges uniformly on $[\delta,2]$ for any $\delta \in (0,1)$, but not on $[0,2]$ and $\int_0^2f(x)g_n(x)dx$ converges to $f(0)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for any continuous function $f$ on $[0,2]$.

My attempt:
(Uniform convergence is clear for me from the supremum norm approach.)
$|\int_0^2f(x)g_n(x)dx-f(0)|=|\int_0^2f(x)g_n(x)dx-\frac{1}{1-a_n}(\int_0^2f(0)g_n(x)dx)|$

$=|\int_0^2g_n(x)\left(f(x)-\frac{f(0)}{1-a_n} \right )dx|$

Now how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that the convergence is not uniform on $[0,2]$ just use the fact that $g_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x$, so uniform convergence would imply that $\int_0^{2} g_n(x) d x\to 0$. This contradicts the fact that $\int_0^{2} g_n(x) d x\to 1$.

Now $\int_0^{2} f(x)g_n(x) dx-f(0)=\int_0^{2} g_n(x)[f(x)-f(0)] dx+o(1)$. Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)| <\epsilon $ for $0 \leq x <\delta$. Split the integral into integrals from $0$ to $\delta$ and $\delta $ to $2$. For the second one use the fact that $f$ is bounded and $\int_{\delta}^{2} g_n(x) dx \to 0$ by uniform convergence.

Comment: It is not the case that $\int_0^{2} f(x)g_n(x) dx-f(0)=\int_0^{2} g_n(x)[f(x)-f(0)] dx$ since $\int_0^2 g_n(x)\, dx = 1-a_n \neq 1$, but there is an easy fix.

Comment: @RRL Thank you. I computed $\int_0^{\infty} g_n(x)dx$ instead of $\int_0^{2} g_n(x)dx$ by mistake. I have corrected the answer.